# Show last 12 months of data on a bar chart according to the slicer choice

Tags: powerbi, dax

my issue is as below:
I hava a Calendar table with dates and Orders Table related to the Calendar table by DateID. I have slicer that allows user to choose month and year from a Calendar table so that the data will be shown only for the choosen month but on one bar chart i would like to show sum of orders by month (so month will be on X-axis) from Orders table not for one month but for the last 12 months where the last month is the one from the slicer. E.g. if user chooses 06-2107 from slicer then the bar chart should show orders data from 07-2016 till 06-2017. Obviously when the slicer and bar chart interact with each other i can see only one month.
I've tried to create a measure in DAX but I failed and the results are not what i expect. If the description is to messy i can provide the pbix file as an example

Comment: the pbix file sure help, pls provide it if you can.

Comment: Ok. I came to the point where I can achieve this partially by using copy of Calendar Table which is not related to other tables. but still there is problem that I would have to use 2 different slicers in one report which i wouldn't like to do. Is there a way to turn off interaction between slicer and bar chart and then still reference to the value of the slicer in the measure used in a bar chart?